# How to use UIScrollViewDelegate in Custom CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I’m making a custom collection view for my app.
I want to call scrollViewWillEndDragging method when I scroll CustomCollectionView on ViewController.

When it drew CustomCollectionView on screen, CommonInit was called but scrollViewWillEndDragging was not called when I scrolled it.

How can I call it?

Here is my code.

**in CustomView**

```
class CustomView: UICollectionView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
    …
   }
}

extension CustomView: UIScrollViewDelegate {

// want to call this method
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
    {
}
```

**in AViewController**

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: CustomView!
    …
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    …
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the collectionView delegate. You can do it in your `CustomView` in `commonInit` like :

`delegate = self`

> Edit

And you should change `UIScrollViewDelegate` to `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` 
inherite from `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Comment: I tried "delegate = self" this in commonInit. But there was a compile error and said "Cannot assign value of type 'CustomView' to type 'UICollectionViewDelegate?". So I changed it as "delegate = self as? UICollectionViewDelegate". But still scrollView method not called..

Comment: @User17373928 My bad, I forget something, you can see my edit :)

Comment: Are you sure your `commonInit` is called ?

Comment: so the problem is in your init, if you call `commonInit` from your `AViewController` is it working ?

Comment: Oh!!! I got it!! So AViewController had CustomView's delegate too on Storyboard. I missed it.. after disconnecting of delegate on AViewController and perfectly work! Thank you for helping me! :-)